Emulator Issue on flutter
INFO | Android emulator version 32.1.12.0 (build_id 9751036) (CL:N/A)
INFO | Found systemPath C:\Users\Zohaib\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-31\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\
WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD
ERROR | is an experimental feature.
ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature.
INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\Zohaib\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled
INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
INFO | IPv4 server found: 192.168.1.

I have tried installing multiple versions of emulator, but nothing works. My flutter is also configured with sdk. I have been getting this error for a week and couldn't find a solution.
Will be greatful if anyone could help

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
